# copy (pg_dump) .sql file to postgresql using Cygwin

Tags: postgresql, cygwin, pg-dump

I have downloaded YELP's sql file and tried to import the sql to my local Postgresql.

I am running postgres on Windows 10 and using Cygwin to execute command that I have found on Google. (it took me forever to use Cygwin instead of windows psql shell)

anyhow, Yelp gives data schema in sql and also data in sql. You may find them a link attached below
https://www.yelp.com/dataset/download

so, basically what I thought was creating an empty table with YELP's schema
the, copy all YELP's data into that table.

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -s mydb < D:/YELP/yelp_schema.sql
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -d mydb < D:/YELP/yelp_sql-2.tar
```

and I am checking my database transaction and it doesn't change nothing and i do not see the table.

this is what i see on Cygwin terminal
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKnL2.png)

and nothing on my postgresql database

Please let me know what I have missed.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

your link asks for email to download. I would suspect yelp to be not transparent for it. So I did not check if they have any advise on their data sets... Anyway you use `pg_dump` to dump the data. to import the resulting file use `psql` for plain sql files and `pg_restore` for custom format ones...

Eg:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -f D:/YELP/yelp_schema.sql
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -s worldmap -Ft D:/YELP/yelp_schema.sql
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

> pg_dump — extract a PostgreSQL database into a script file or other
>   archive file

Comment: it really doesn't help. the schema file has @, ' and i dont think it can read it somehow. it's weird :(

Comment: you should post the exact excerpt from sql file where it fails if you want help

Comment: pg_restore, i get this error "pg_restore: too many command-line arguments (first is "-Ft")
Try "pg_restore --help" for more information."